# changing value in a column if value is greater than 0.6 in another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in dataframe one is prediction_class which is having 2 values 0 and 1 another column is predict_probabilty which is having values between 0 and 1. I want to change value in prediction_class to 0 if value in predict_probabilty is lesser than 0.60 and value in prediction_class to 1 if value in predict_probabilty is greater than 0.60.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
prediction_class   predict_probabilty
      1                  0.90
      1                  0.85
      0                  0.75
      0                  0.89
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['prediction_class'] = np.where(df['predict_probabilty'].lt(0.6), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Compre for greater like `0.6` and cast mask to integers:

```
df['prediction_class'] = df['predict_probabilty'].gt(0.6).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['prediction_class'] = df['predict_probabilty'].gt(0.6).view('i1')
```

Or:

```
df['prediction_class'] = np.where(df['predict_probabilty'].gt(0.6), 1, 0)
```

Comment: @Data_guy - yes, added another solutions.